# Checking if there's any forbidden extension in the array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if there's any forbidden extension in the array elements. How to do it?

```
$allowed_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg');
```

```
Array
(
   [0] => C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_1.jpg
   [1] => C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_2.jpg
   [2] => C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_3.jpg
   [3] => C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_4.jpg
   [4] => C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_5.png
)
```

Comment: No, because I don't know how to check it in all the array elements.

Comment: @test That's just your standard code loop to go through all the array elements.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

there is multiple ways, you could use `pathinfo()` for example like here:

```
$allowed_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg');

$files = [
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_1.jpg",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_2.jpg",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_3.jpg",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_4.jpg",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_5.png",
];

$not_allowed_files = array_filter($files, function($var) use ($allowed_types) {
    $path_info = pathinfo($var);
    return !in_array($path_info['extension'], $allowed_types);
});
```

(not tested)

Comment: This will check if there is any other extension in any of the elements than the one allowed?

Comment: yes and it returns an array with the elements that have an extension wich is not allowed, if there is none the result is emtpy.

Answer (score 0):

This will join the `$allowed_types` on the OR `|` operator and check for the extensions and return an array of ones that DO NOT match:

```
if(preg_grep('/'.implode('|', $allowed_types).'$/i', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT)) {
    // disallowed file types
}
```

In your example it would return those that do not match `jpg|jpeg$` which means:

- Match `jpg` OR `jpeg` at the end `$` of the string
- The `i` after the closing `/` is for upper or lower case (remove `i` if you want)

If you actually want to know which ones do not match, then:

```
if($bad = preg_grep('/'.implode('|', $allowed_types).'$/i', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT)) {
    print_r($bad);
}
```

Then `$bad` will contain the entries that DO NOT match.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I refuse to answer questions that do not include a coding attempt, but I am compelled to chime in on this instance because suboptimal/incorrect advice has been provided and I want to help future researchers.

Regex should be avoided unless it provides a valuable advantage -- this is one of those cases.  My snippet will require just two function calls instead of 2n+1 function calls.

Implode your whitelisted extension values with pipes which represent "OR" in regex.  Wrap the pipe-delimited string in parentheses to contain the logic, the write a `$` at the end to demand that the extension values are only matched at the end of the string.  Use the `i` pattern modifier to make the whole pattern case-insensitive.  Because your array values only have alphabetical characters, there is no need to call `preg_quote()` to supply escaping slashes.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/73jlT))

```
$allowed_types = ['jpg', 'jpeg'];

$files = [
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_1.jpg",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/jpeg_2.gif",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_3.jpeg",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/1597335125_4.jpg",
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/jpg_5.png",
];

if ($disallowed = preg_grep('/(' . implode('|', $allowed_types) . ')$/i', $files, PREG_GREP_INVERT)) {
    var_export($disallowed);
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/jpeg_2.gif',
  4 => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/media/images/jpg_5.png',
)
```

This answer is very similar to [Abra's](https://3v4l.org/Vnu4K), but the flaw in his answer is in the missing parentheses.  Without the parentheses, the "end of string" `$` will only apply to the final extension in the pipe-delimited string and render the pattern incorrect.

If you don't need the whitelist array to be dynamic, you could hard code your regex as:

```
/jpe?g$/i
```

If you are generating your input array of files from a directory scan or `glob()` call, then you should use `glob()`'s filtering features.  Check the php manual.

---

To merely check if ANY files have an invalid extension with the best performing `o` (little o), then use a classic `foreach()` loop with a conditional `break`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pjG6L))

```
$hasInvalidFile = false;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed_types)) {
        $hasInvalidFile = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_export($hasInvalidFile);
```